# 301 Redirect issue - ignoring redirected path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble with a redirect that I thought should be pretty simple.

Here's what I have:

```
redirect 301 /datatools.php  https://www.newsite.com/?p=1613
```

However, when I type `www.oldsite.com/datatools.php`, it keeps taking me to `www.newsitecom/datatools.php` instead of the URL that I listed in the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This is how [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) works

> Then any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. *Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.*

This is the reason why `datatools.php` is appended to `https://www.newsite.com/`.

---

If you want to replace the source URL, you can try [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), which allows to throw away all or parts of the original request URI

```
RedirectMatch /datatools.php  https://www.newsite.com/?p=1613
```

When everything works as it should, you may change the status code to `301`. *Never* test with [`301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

Comment: Thank you!  That worked. I thought I tried the RedirectMatch but must have mess it up.